# Cron, xconf-query and Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, cron

I have updated my Xubuntu to the 14.04 version. Unfortunately, I am experiencing a problem.
I have a script, named earth, updating the wallpaper of my desktop. Here is the code

```
#!/bin/sh
nice -n 19 /home/hp/.xplanet/download_xplanet_cloudmap --debug=1;
nice xplanet -projection rectangular -geometry 1366x768 -window -num_times 1 -output /home/hp/.xplanet/images/earth.png;
# nice xplanet -geometry 1280x1024 -num_times 1 -longitude 15 -latitude 38 -output /home/hp/.xplanet/images/earth.png
# gconftool-2 -t string -s /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename /home/hp/.xplanet/images/earth.png;
xfconf-query --channel xfce4-desktop --property /backdrop/screen0/monitor0/image-path --set "/home/hp/.xplanet/images/earth.png"
xfconf-query --channel xfce4-desktop --property /backdrop/screen0/monitor1/image-path --set "/home/hp/.xplanet/images/earth.png"
xfconf-query --channel xfce4-desktop --property /backdrop/screen0/monitorLVDS-0/workspace0/last-image --set "/home/hp/.xplanet/images/earth.png"
```

When I run the script in a terminal, it works. But, if I add the running of the script to crontab, with the command `crontab -e` and including the line

```
00,20,40 * * * * ( export DISPLAY=:0.0; sh /home/hp/.xplanet/earth )
```

it doesn't work.

Particularly, the commands with `xfconf-query` don't run. It worked in Xubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exact cron line. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) for help on formatting your question (though you seem to have figured it out already). Your issue is probably that [you also need to add](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68063) `XAUTHORITY=~user/.Xauthority` to the line but we need the exact line to be sure.

Comment: Same problem, the command `xfconf-query` does not seem to work when invoked from `crontab`.  Not sure why?

Comment: I have found a simple solution, posted as an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1024588/179725

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/805455/xfconf-query-crontab-failed-to-init-libxfconf-unable-to-autolaunch-a-dbus-da