# xfconf-query, crontab, "Failed to init libxfconf: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11."

Tags: bash, scripts, xubuntu, cron, xfce

I have Xubuntu 16.04, and am trying to run the following script from crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash

status=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-on-ac)
vid="/dev/video0"

if [ -z "$status" ]; then
    exit 1
fi

if [ -e "$vid" -a "$status" -gt 14 ]; then
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-on-ac -s 14
elif [ ! -e "$vid" -a "$status" -eq 14 ]; then 
    xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-on-ac -s 25
fi
```

It works perfectly when run it from the terminal. However, from crontab I get this error.

```
Failed to init libxfconf: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11.
```

Here is my crontab entry. It was edited using `crontab -e`.

```
*/5 * * * * (bash -x /home/brock/bin/vid-power) > /home/brock/Desktop/debug.log 2>&1
```

Here is the full output of my debug.log.

```
~/Desktop$ cat debug.log 
++ xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-on-ac
Failed to init libxfconf: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11.
+ status=
+ vid=/dev/video0
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ exit 1
```

I have tried various solutions, including [the comment here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521697/cron-xconf-query-and-xubuntu-14-04) and [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28463/run-a-dbus-program-in-crontab-how-to-know-about-the-session-id), but none have worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did the following, it allows me to invoke `xfconf-query` from `crontab`:

First, get the value of this variable:

```
echo $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
```

You will see a path like this:

```
unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

Then use, in the script executed by `crontab`:

```
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus
xfconf-query ...
```

Credit: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1706208#p1706208

Answer (score -1):

I will just set this script to run as a Session and Startup > Application Autostart item instead.

```
#!/bin/bash   

vid="/dev/video0"

while true; do
    status=$(xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-on-ac)
    if [ -e "$vid" -a "$status" -gt 14 ]; then
        xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-on-ac -s 14
    elif [ ! -e "$vid" -a "$status" -eq 14 ]; then 
        xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/inactivity-on-ac -s 25
    fi
    sleep 5m
done
```

Answer (score -1):

In order for the `xfconf-query` command to work under `cron` environment you need to have the following in the bash script, for example:

```
# set today's wallpaper; first set one env variable for xfconf-query
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$UID/bus
xfconf-query -c xfce4-desktop -p /backdrop/screen0/monitorVGA-0/workspace0/last-image -s "${filename}"
```

Credit: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1706208#p1706208